# Histogram using d3js

Tags: d3.js, charts, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram chart for a income range breaks with counts in each break. I picked up the example from one the basic histogram bl.ocks .Below is the code for this. How could I generate histograms to show ranges of incomes on the x-axis and count on y.

https://jsfiddle.net/snt1/cLu6f1nb/6/

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var all = [{
  "name": "Home Value",
  "code": "HOME_VALUE",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Housing Value   Under $10,000",
    "code": "Q084002",
    "count": 78
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $10,000 to $14,999",
    "code": "Q084003",
    "count": 73
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $15,000 to $19,999",
    "code": "Q084004",
    "count": 30
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $20,000 to $25,000",
    "code": "Q084005",
    "count": 60
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $25,000 to $29,999",
    "code": "Q084006",
    "count": 40
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $30,000 to $34,999",
    "code": "Q084007",
    "count": 21
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $35,000 to $39,999",
    "code": "Q084008",
    "count": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $40,000 to $49,999",
    "code": "Q084009",
    "count": 44
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $50,000 to $59,999",
    "code": "Q084010",
    "count": 85
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $60,000 to $69,999",
    "code": "Q084011",
    "count": 93
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $70,000 to $79,999",
    "code": "Q084012",
    "count": 208
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $80,000 to $89,999",
    "code": "Q084013",
    "count": 231
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $90,000 to $99,999",
    "code": "Q084014",
    "count": 419
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $100,000 to $124,999",
    "code": "Q084015",
    "count": 1491
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $125,000 to $149,999",
    "code": "Q084016",
    "count": 1135
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $150,000 to $174,999",
    "code": "Q084017",
    "count": 866
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $175,000 to $199,999",
    "code": "Q084018",
    "count": 472
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $200,000 to $249,999",
    "code": "Q084019",
    "count": 654
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $250,000 to $299,999",
    "code": "Q084020",
    "count": 536
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $300,000 to $399,999",
    "code": "Q084021",
    "count": 409
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $400,000 to $499,999",
    "code": "Q084022",
    "count": 145
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $500,000 to $749,999",
    "code": "Q084023",
    "count": 147
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $750,000 to $999,999",
    "code": "Q084024",
    "count": 128
  }]
}]
var data = all[0].children;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.name = +d.name;
  d.count = +d.count;
});
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var bins = d3.histogram()
  .domain(x.domain())
  .thresholds(x.ticks(20))
  (data);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
// Coerce types.

data.forEach(function(bin) {
  bin.name = +bin.name;
  bin.count = +bin.count;
});

// Normalize each bin to so that height = quantity/width;
// see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Examples
for (var i = 1, n = bins.length, bin; i < n; i++) {
  bin = bins[i];
  bin.offset = bins[i - 1].name;
  bin.width = bin.name - bin.offset;
  bin.height = bin.count / bin.width;
}

// Drop the first bin, since it's incorporated into the next.
bins.shift();

// Set the scale domain.
x.domain([0, d3.max(bins.map(function(d) {
  return d.offset + d.width;
}))]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(bins.map(function(d) {
  return d.height;
}))]);

// Add the bins.
svg.selectAll(".bin")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bin")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.offset);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.width) - 1;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.height);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.height);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.2/d3.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your question/code is a misunderstanding of what is a *bar chart* and what is a *histogram*. Don't feel bad, a lot of people get this wrong.

As I said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604224/5768908): Bar charts, by their very nature, are made of bars representing a **categorical variable**. It means that the bars are positioned over a label that represents a categorical variable, i.e., a **qualitative** variable. When I said *"a lot of people get this wrong"* I was talking about the difference between a bar chart and a histogram: both use rectangles to encode data, but in a histogram, unlike a bar chart, the label represents a **quantitative variable**. At least a half dozen times a month I see someone here at S.O. posting a question about *histograms* which are in fact bar charts, or about *bar charts* which are in fact histograms.

Back to your question: your data is not suitable for a histogram. As I said, a histogram represents a quantitative variable. So, this would be an adequate data for a histogram:

```
[{
  value: 200000,
  code: "Q084001"
}, {
  value: 250000,
  code: "Q084002"
}, {
  value: 180000,
  code: "Q084003"
}, {
  value: 490000,
  code: "Q084001"
},
//etc...
]
```

With a data like that you could create the bins the way you want, according to the variable `value`.

However, right now, you have **categorical variables**, which are these:

```
["Housing Value Under $10,000", 
  "Housing Value $10,000 to $14,999", 
  "Housing Value $15,000 to $19,999", 
  //etc...
];
```

You **cannot** create a histogram with this data.

**Solution**: Just create a good old bar chart.

This is a bar chart with your data and minimal changes in your code:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 180,
  left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var all = [{
  "name": "Home Value",
  "code": "HOME_VALUE",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Housing Value   Under $10,000",
    "code": "Q084002",
    "count": 78
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $10,000 to $14,999",
    "code": "Q084003",
    "count": 73
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $15,000 to $19,999",
    "code": "Q084004",
    "count": 30
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $20,000 to $25,000",
    "code": "Q084005",
    "count": 60
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $25,000 to $29,999",
    "code": "Q084006",
    "count": 40
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $30,000 to $34,999",
    "code": "Q084007",
    "count": 21
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $35,000 to $39,999",
    "code": "Q084008",
    "count": 8
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $40,000 to $49,999",
    "code": "Q084009",
    "count": 44
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $50,000 to $59,999",
    "code": "Q084010",
    "count": 85
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $60,000 to $69,999",
    "code": "Q084011",
    "count": 93
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $70,000 to $79,999",
    "code": "Q084012",
    "count": 208
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $80,000 to $89,999",
    "code": "Q084013",
    "count": 231
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value  $90,000 to $99,999",
    "code": "Q084014",
    "count": 419
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $100,000 to $124,999",
    "code": "Q084015",
    "count": 1491
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $125,000 to $149,999",
    "code": "Q084016",
    "count": 1135
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $150,000 to $174,999",
    "code": "Q084017",
    "count": 866
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $175,000 to $199,999",
    "code": "Q084018",
    "count": 472
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $200,000 to $249,999",
    "code": "Q084019",
    "count": 654
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $250,000 to $299,999",
    "code": "Q084020",
    "count": 536
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $300,000 to $399,999",
    "code": "Q084021",
    "count": 409
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $400,000 to $499,999",
    "code": "Q084022",
    "count": 145
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $500,000 to $749,999",
    "code": "Q084023",
    "count": 147
  }, {
    "name": "Housing Value $750,000 to $999,999",
    "code": "Q084024",
    "count": 128
  }]
}]
var data = all[0].children;


// Set the scale domain.

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .padding(0.2);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

// Add the bins.
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.name);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x.bandwidth();
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.count);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.count);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-12,86) rotate(-90)");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```